# Hartshorne - Geometry: Euclid and Beyond: Given two lines and a point, construct a circle passing through the point and tangent to both lines.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation, homothety

[image]

What is a proper solution for this problem? It has been bugging me for a good while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The key word is homothety.

First just draw any circle with center at $C$ which touch bot $l$ and $m$. Then draw a line through peak and $P$. Mark where this line cuts circle with $A$ and $B$. Now draw a parallel through $P$ to $CA$ (or $CB$). Mark a point where this parallel cuts angle bisector. This is the center of circle(s) you want.

Comment: Very clever, thanks.